# What is the equivalent of CQL count() in Java driver

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, datastax-java-driver

I want to run the following query using Java driver. In `CQL`, to find count of a partition, I can do `select count(*) from table where field1 = “x” ;`. What is the equivalent of `count()` in `QueryBuilder`? So far, to find the no. of rows returned, I have used

```
val resultSet = session.execute(partitionSizeQuery)
/*is this the most efficient way to find the size of ResultSet??*/
val resultSetSize = resultSet.all.size
```

where Query is `QueryBuilder.select().from(tableName).where(QueryBuilder.eq("field1", somevalue))`. But I am not sure if this is the right way

Answer (score 4):

Equivalent to count() in querybuilder is `QueryBuilder.select().countAll()`. I would instead just iterate through the resultSet and incrementing a counter as it will page through more slowly while `count` does some things internally that can fan out the request which can turn into thousands of internal queries (very expensive). Iterating through resultSet is better than `all` so it wont try to load entire thing into memory if it has to page (result > fetchsize).

Using `count` is very expensive and there are a few cases you can expect it to timeout. So especially if its something that can be called frequently you sohuld avoid it.

Have you considered using a different table to keep track of entries you added? The extra book keeping is a more work but it will result in efficient queries.

If there are TTLs or something that makes it difficult to track you can also use a job (ie spark or iterating through like above) to just keep the second "count" table, and just have it not up to date all the time.